# How to save matplotlib to folder

Tags: python, matplotlib, directory

I want to save plot in my folder. If the folder doesn't exist, it will automally create new folder. I thought it was like this

```
plt.savefig('output/output.png')
```

But it doesn't work. I get an error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to create the folder first.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience saving the file path as opposed to coding it into a string avoids this error.
Something like

```
current_directory_path = os.getcwd()

plot_name = 'result.png'

plot_path = os.path.join(current_directory_path, plot_name)
```

This should then allow you to save with the usual plt.savefig()

```
plt.savefig(plot_path)
```